# How to test performance of my virtual reality game in different android devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, performance-testing, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am developing an Virtual reality game for Cardboard(Android OS).
Currently I am testing in the availabe phone with me.
But before releasing the game I want to test it in all virtual reality suppported devices.
So I am searching for any services that helps me to test my game in terms of performance, UI ..etc, but unable to find any such services for testing game performance.
Found services that are helpng to test apps, But I need to test performance as well, that to for VR game.

Are there any services that provides virtual devices(Emulators) that are currently used by industry to test VR game developed in unity3d in terms of  performance, compatibality, UI scaling ..etc

Comment: Here: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/Profiling/Overview/

Answer (score 1):

There is Firebase test lab that you can use for accessing test devices - https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/

however, you'll need to run the tests by yourself.